# Problem creating a database with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-error-1005

I'm having a problem with a SQL query in my PHP Application. When the user access it for the first time, the app executes this query to create all the database:

```
CREATE TABLE `databases` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `driver` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `server` text NOT NULL,
  `user` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `database` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `modules`
--

CREATE TABLE `modules` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `modules_data`
--

CREATE TABLE `modules_data` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `module_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `value` tinytext,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `fk_modules_data_modules` (`module_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=184 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `modules_position`
--

CREATE TABLE `modules_position` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tab_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `module_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `column` smallint(1) default NULL,
  `line` smallint(1) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`,`tab_id`,`module_id`),
  KEY `fk_modules_order_users` (`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_modules_order_tabs` (`tab_id`),
  KEY `fk_modules_order_modules` (`module_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tabs`
--

CREATE TABLE `tabs` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `columns` smallint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tabs_has_modules`
--

CREATE TABLE `tabs_has_modules` (
  `tab_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `module_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tab_id`,`module_id`),
  KEY `fk_tabs_has_modules_tabs` (`tab_id`),
  KEY `fk_tabs_has_modules_modules` (`module_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `login` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `user_level` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `fk_users_user_levels` (`user_level`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users_has_tabs`
--

CREATE TABLE `users_has_tabs` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tab_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `order` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
  `columns_width` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`,`tab_id`),
  KEY `fk_users_has_tabs_users` (`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_users_has_tabs_tabs` (`tab_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_levels`
--

CREATE TABLE `user_levels` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `level` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_meta`
--

CREATE TABLE `user_meta` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `key` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `value` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `fk_user_meta_users` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `modules_data`
--
ALTER TABLE `modules_data`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_modules_data_modules` FOREIGN KEY (`module_id`) REFERENCES `modules` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Constraints for table `modules_position`
--
ALTER TABLE `modules_position`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_modules_order_modules` FOREIGN KEY (`module_id`) REFERENCES `modules` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_modules_order_tabs` FOREIGN KEY (`tab_id`) REFERENCES `tabs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_modules_order_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Constraints for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_users_user_levels` FOREIGN KEY (`user_level`) REFERENCES `user_levels` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Constraints for table `user_meta`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_meta`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_meta_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

INSERT INTO `user_levels` VALUES(1, 10);
INSERT INTO `user_levels` VALUES(2, 1);


INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(1, 'admin', 'password', 'changethis@testing.com', NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO `user_meta` VALUES (NULL, 1, 'last_tab', 1);
```

In some environments i get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005
>   Can't create table 'dms.databases'
>   (errno: 150)

I tried everything that I could find on Google but nothing works.

The strange part is that if I run this query in PhpMyAdmin he creates my database, without any error.

Comment: The database exists, but the tables don't.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely to be in the constraints part of your queries.

The error 150 is mentioned in the InnoDB Documentation:

> If you re-create a table that was
>   dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key
>   constraints referencing it. It must
>   have the right column names and types,
>   and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys, as stated earlier. If
>   these are not satisfied, MySQL returns
>   error number 1005 and refers to error
>   150 in the error message.
>
> If MySQL reports an error number 1005 from a CREATE TABLE statement,
>   and the error message refers to error
>   150, table creation failed because a
>   foreign key constraint was not
>   correctly formed. Similarly, if an
>   ALTER TABLE fails and it refers to
>   error 150, that means a foreign key
>   definition would be incorrectly formed
>   for the altered table. You can use
>   SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS to display a
>   detailed explanation of the most
>   recent InnoDB foreign key error in the
>   server.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

It will also occur if the definitions of the references are not identical (i.e. one is signed, one is unsigned bigint) or mixing unique indexes over several columns with them.

Comment: Perhaps an issue with missing an index?